# Help embedding OpenLayers map in Eclipse BIRT report

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, cartography, layers, reports

I have this code, it displays the zoom buttons only but it doesn't display my map.

What could be the problem?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://openlayers.eastasia/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script src="http://openlayers.eastasia/api/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var width = $(document).width() - 10;
        var height = $(document).height() - 10;   
        var widthpx = width + "px";
        var heightpx = height + "px"; 
        var zoomLevel = 11;

        if (height > 644)
            zoomLevel = 11;
        else if (height > 322)
            zoomLevel = 10;
        else if (height > 160)
            zoomLevel = 9;  

        $("body").css("height", heightpx);
    </script>
    <style>
        #labels {
            font-size: normal;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
        #scaleline-id {
            margin: 10px;
            font-size: small;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
    <div style="background: white;" id="map"></div>
    <div id="scaleline-id"></div>
    <div id="labels"></div>

    <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
        $("#map").css("width", widthpx);
        $("#map").css("height", heightpx);

        var gma_box = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
            120.7500, 14.2465,
            121.2314, 14.8872
        );
            function init() {
        var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map",
            {
                projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3395"),
        //      center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(120.99808606793, 14.563722625875),
                maxExtent: gma_box,
                restrictedExtent: gma_box,
                maxResolution: 1.40625,
                units: 'degrees',
            }
            );

        var wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Business Areas", {
                isBaseLayer: true,
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                    version: "1.1.0",
                    url: "/geoserver/wfs",
                    featurePrefix: "nrw",
                    featureType: "Maynilad_Business_Areas",
                    featureNS: "http://eastasia-tech.com",
                    srsName: "EPSG:3395"
                })
            });

        map.addLayer(wfs);
        map.zoomTo(zoomLevel);
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should double check that the web service you are using is actually responding. It sounds like you have a map, but that either (1) you aren't receiving the data you expect, or (2) that data is not being rendered properly onto the map.

Comment: thanks, you're right it's being blocked because of XSS protection.